# With a 50 limit using importHTML is there method to increase data rows

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Using importHTML in Google sheets is it possible to shape the following

Sheet1:Rows 1-30 only
Sheet2:Rows 31-61 only

This would increase the data limit from 50 to 60 but with two sheets.

I understand it is possible to use query

Limit and offset
Limit the number of rows
Offset skips a number of rows

"Select* LIMIT 2 OFFSET 4"

This maybe a solution

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add more details like the web app name that you are using,  what you tried and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Welcomer. You say a possible solution may be to use `query` to get around the 50 formula limit that Google places on import formula. Have you tried this, what result did you get?

Comment: Under a test it worked however the url I was using was also restricting to 50 table data and I was unable to access beyond the 50 rows limit. Even with limit and offset.